# Set SOAP request default values using Spring and Axis2

Tags: java, spring, soap, apache-axis

I don't know if this is even possible, I've been looking around and haven't found anything even related to this... or maybe I'm just not using the right terms to find it.

The problem is this.. let's say I have this request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsd="http://request.dto.webservices.com/xsd">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <impl:testServiceMethod>
            <xsd1:booleanField1>?</xsd1:booleanField1>
        </impl:testServiceMethod>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What's currently happening is that on the back-end side the `booleanField1` `(which is Boolean)`, is received as `false` instead of `null`. To get the `null` I have to remove the field from the request.

Is there a way to set anywhere on the code that behavior?